# Simple way to add elements from one list to another list

Tags: c++, stl

What is the "correct" way to add all elements from one std::list to another one?

```
void
Node::addChilds(const NodeList *list)
{
    for(NodeList::const_iterator i = list->begin();
        i != list->end();
        ++i)
        {
            this->m_childs.push_back(*i);
        }
}
```

I thought about std::copy, but afaik for copy I have to resize the destination list, backup the end iterator (before resize) etc.

I'm searching for a single-line statement.

Comment: What is `NodeList`?  How is `m_childs` declared?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use a [`back_insert_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_insert_iterator). If `std::list<T>` is the type of `m_childs`,

```
std::copy(list.begin(), list.end(),
          std::back_insert_iterator<std::list<T> >(m_childs));
```

Comment: both this and @ybungalobill are correct.  I prefer this however.  Here's why: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152815/stl-use-member-functions-or-functions-in-algorithm/4156380#4156380]

Comment: I would have thought member function `list::insert` would be more efficient.  Any idea whether that's right?

Comment: On Linux/x86 running on an Intel Core2 @1.86GHz, GCC 4.3.2, filling a list with 10000000 elements, copying that to another list and printing the second element takes ca. 2.5s wall-clock time, 2.1s user time, independent of whether `copy` or `insert` is used.

Answer (score 13):

```
this->m_childs.insert(this->m_childs.end(), list->begin(), list->end());
```

Answer (score 12):

If the elements should be moved, you can use **splice**. Otherwise copy them, as explained by ybungalobill or larsmans.

Answer (score 3):

Scott Meyers writes about this specific subject in "*Effective STL*", in item 5 (and mentions `splice` in item 4). He prefers ybungalobill's version, but mostly because he thinks the code is cleaner and clearer since it emphasizes the word 'insert' and not the word 'copy'.

Almost all uses of `std::copy` which uses a iterator (like `back_inserter`) can be replaced with calls to range member functions (like `.insert(position, begin, end)`).

`splice` is a constant-time member function, so it will be faster if it is applicable in this specific case.